# What killed Ferdinand Magellan?

Tags: death, philippines

Did Ferdinand Magellan die because of a poisonous arrow that Indians shot him with?

Comment: Always nice to see new faces here! However, you should be aware that we generally expect questions to not be easily answerable by doing something as simple as checking [the subject's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Magellan#Death_in_the_Philippines). Unless of course there's some justifiable reason you have to believe that Wikipedia might have it wrong?

Comment: Hmmm...to be fair, the WP page does have that section marked with "better source needed", and the same source does also mention that he'd been hit earlier with a poisoned arrow. So there might indeed be cause for doubt.

Comment: Magellan was killed in Philippines, not America

Comment: @OON - Yes, the **real** Indies. I don't think they are considered part of the "East Indies" anymore, but they were during Magellan's time, so I could see where someone might get confused. Particularly when reading first-hand reports that may talk about "Indians".

Comment: @T.E.D. now I understand why sempaiscuba was so paranoid over my source for Tyndale's trial. I guess it is a prerequisite here.

Comment: @T.E.D. Actually, in my opinion there is no country called India in general. The Native Americans go by their own names, such as the Souix or the Navajo, same goes with Indonesia and the Philippines. India? No, call it Bharat, the name it was called far before the British arrived.

Answer (score 4):

According to the source of Wikipedia:

"they shot the captain [Magellan] through the right leg with a poisoned arrow...
[while the battle continue...]
One of them wounded him [Magellan] on the left leg with a large cutlass, which resembles a scimitar, only being larger. That caused the captain to fall face downward, when immediately they rushed upon him with iron and bamboo spears and with their cutlasses, until they killed [Magellan] our mirror, our light, our comfort, and our true guide."

Hence, we might say that Magellan was wounded by a poisonous arrow. But he was killed by other means.

Source [here](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/magellan.htm)

Comment: I think it is worth addding in the body of this good answer that the primary source is "the diary of the Italian Antonio Pigafetta. Antonio was not a member of the crew but an adventurous tourist who paid for his passage."